How to get rid of this extra space in my dropdown menu?
I am trying to make a commercial website from scratch as a beginner, and I am currently following along a youtube tutorial for help. I finished the feature entirely, but the past few days I been stuck with an issue that has been frusterating me a little, since I don't know what is causing this to happen:
Drop Down Menu
There is this extra space that has appeared beside the Language switch options. It has all this unnecessary space I don't need nor want. It occurred after I used display: block, so I assume it has something to do with the problem I am facing.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> China Goods </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/testing/index.css">
</head>

<body>


    <nav class = "navBar"> 

        <ul> 

            <li> <a href = ""> Home </a> </li>
            <li> <a href = ""> Sign Up </a> </li>
            <li> <a href = ""> Shopping Cart </a> </li>

            <div class = "languageBar"> 
          
                <li> <a href = ""> Language </a>  </li>

                <div class = "languageContent"> 

                    <li> <a href = ""> English </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href = ""> Chinese </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href = ""> Japanese </a> </li>
        
                </div>

            </div>
        

        </ul>

    </nav>
   

    <main> 



    </main>


    
</body>
</html>


* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    
    
}

body{

    margin: 0px;


}


.navBar ul{

    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0% , 25%) ;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

    width: max-content;

    display: flex;

    justify-content: flex-start;

    position: relative;

    left: 800px;

    top: 50px;
    
    
}

.navBar a{

   color: white;
   text-decoration: none ;
   padding: 15px;
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   
}

.navBar a:hover{

    background-color: hsl(0, 84%, 47%);

    
}

.navBar li{

    float: center;
    
    
}

/* Impacts the Language Bar */
 .languageBar .languageContent{
    display:none;

}

.languageBar:hover .languageContent{
   
}




I attempted to use Display: flex and float:left, alongside overflow:hidden in order to get rid of this extra space, but nothing happened. Also attempted line-height as well, but that only changed the height of the text, and didn't get rid of the unwanted space.

The language hover content needs to be absolutely positioned in order to prevent the nav bar itself growing. See also this tutorial.


body {
  margin: 0px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0% , 25%);
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: hsl(0, 84%, 47%);
}

.languageBar {
  position: relative;
}

.languageBar>div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0% , 25%);
}

.languageBar:hover>div {
  display: flex;
}
<nav> 
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">Sign Up</a>
  <a href="">Shopping Cart</a>
  <div class="languageBar">
      <a href="">Language</a>
      <div>
        <a href="">English (Australia)</a>
        <a href="">Chinese</a>
        <a href="">Japanese</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>



